# Categorical variables in MultinomialNB Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, categorical-data

I'm new to Python, and here is a simple question regarding setting up X_train in MultinomialNB.

So I want to predict a target ("A1",'A2,..."A5") using two **categorical features**: **Weekday** with 7 unique values ('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'), and **Location** with 5 unique values ('A','B','C','D','E').

Here is what I am doing:

- using `pd.getdummies` to convert Weekday and Location to a vector of binary input
- using `LabelEncoder` to convert target to numerical values
- split data into training/testing

Then I do following (using scikit-learn):

```
clf=MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

So my questions are:

- Are above steps correct? In particular, **is "get_dummies" the best way to treat categorical features?**
- By doing above, the `X_train` will be in shape (N_samples, 12), in which 12 comes from 7 (vectorized Weekday) and 5 (vectorized location). Is this correct setup for this problem?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your steps sound correct. I do find that `get_dummies()` is the easiest way to prepare **unordered categorical features** for scikit-learn. However, you can actually drop the "baseline level" for each categorical variable, reducing the number of features to 10 (6 + 4 instead of 7 + 5). Also, keep in mind that if you have an **ordered categorical feature**, it may make sense to keep it as one feature and translate the categories to "sensible" numerical values.

In part 2 of [this Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/justmarkham/DAT8/blob/master/notebooks/13_advanced_model_evaluation.ipynb), I show examples of everything mentioned above.